# Composer REST server auth

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have a question about rest-server. In my project I don't won't to use rest server as direct backend, I wanna have one more api, which will send different requests. So, my question is, what kind of auth I need to choose? (auth need for multi-user mode, I want to send transactions from different participants) Thank you)

Is it possible to use composer-rest-server not just for log in but for sign up too, if real users will not make requests, but my own api will register them on rest-server automatically and then on their behalf will do all the transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of multiuser interaction - albeit using REST APIs (but the principle is the same - think: different REST (or API) clients connecting to the business network, on the blockchain, with their business network cards (part of which contains an identity) in their own private wallets and therefore blockchain identities issuing transactions signed by that identity) is shown here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-multiuser

Composer REST server supports over 300+ authentication strategies (see more here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html) so you can choose an auth strategy such as PassportJS strategies http://www.passportjs.org/ as appropriate to your organisation. Once a user authentications, there is a callback to a point in the application where it connects to the business network, and thereafter uses its business network card to interact with the business network deployed to the peers on the blockchain network. Those business network cards can be in the Cloud stored as cloud-based wallets or stored on disk in a secured environment

To connect to a business network programatically, see the discussion here -> [Hyperledger Composer Web application user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893410/hyperledger-composer-web-application-user-authentication)

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html