# composer-rest-server authentication important questions

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer

I am very new to Hyperledger composer, so maybe I understand something wrong.

My situation:

I have a network with several cards. Lets say I have (admin@basic-network) and (user1@basic-network). Now I have created a composer-rest-server with google authentication via this tutorial: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest

Everything works fine but I have 2 questions:

1) Right now everyone can login with his google Account and gets the access key. Is this supposed to be? Because actually it's a private blockchain, and I thought that a Administrator needs to define who can join the network.

2) With the wallet, I need to import a card which is necessary to create api calls. But let's say there are 10x Users who access the Api. When I import my card, everyone else who is accessing the api can see the imported card with GET "/wallet" and can also use it for his Api calls?

I think that I don't see something or that I'm not thinking correct at some point. Hopefully you can help me here.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer REST server auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148467/composer-rest-server-auth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you log in with google, you can call api without login error. however, if you haven't imported the card, you won't be able to interact with the network. And only admin can create participants, identifiers, and cards
2. Each token will manage different cards. unless those tokens also import your card, they cannot interact with the network with your card. Don't foget [enabling multiple user mode for the REST server](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/integrating/enabling-multiuser)

I hope to help you

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful answer