# Signing transactions with certificates on the go, in composer rest server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

In comopser rest server I know its advisable to store network card with composer rest server. Now what if I dont want to store my network card in rest server wallet. How to sign transaction indvidually by passing my certificate during calls to rest server.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Cloud-based wallets see ->  https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/business-network/cloud-wallets available from v0.18.x onwards
2. You can use the Composer JS APIs to connect to the business network with a business network card, and then transact on the network, as that blockchain identity. Example here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/pii-network/test/pii.js#L119 onwards (instead of MemoryCardStore shown here, you can use FileSystemCardStore to work with a card in your wallet store)

See also [Hyperledger Composer Web application user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893410/hyperledger-composer-web-application-user-authentication) for more information

Comment: Actually I want to know about the option if I don't want to store my credentials anywhere , but just sign them while posting any transaction.