# Web app interaction with Composer in multi user

Tags: redis, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, node-redis, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have a scenario where web app(node application) has to interacts with Composer-REST server. The application would be accessible by different participants of an organization.

There is an authentication server which creates the session for the user when he logs in.

I am not sure **how to get a user's card(composer card)** to interact with REST server. I found that there is a *composer-wallet-redis* which can be used to store the cards. But, not sure **how to access it by web application**? We create cards by composer cli then how redis would have that information?

**Do we need to manually export the cards to redis server? If so, How do we tackle new participant use cases where we have to generate cards through code?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On redis server - see the docs -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/cloud-wallets

See also this Stack answer -> [Hyperledger Composer Web application user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893410/hyperledger-composer-web-application-user-authentication)

and finally there are knowledge wiki resources https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/developing-multi-user-application-using-the-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-b3b88e857ccc and https://medium.com/coinmonks/hyperledger-composer-api-for-managing-business-network-cards-80f215db27f7 for more information

Comment: Does it mean that here redis is being used as a MSP server? Do I have to use redis instead of fabric-CA in dev environment if I have to test the functionality?

Comment: No - you don't use instead of. Redis is an objectstore for storing the card wallets in the Cloud. These are accessible to the rightful application users, that need to interact with the business network on the blockchain.  The Fabric CA server is responsible for issuing certificates for an organisation on the blockchain network (from which the certificate/key is extracted and form a key part of the business network card for users from that org) - so it has a different function, to what the redis cloud wallet store is designed to do.