# What is the best option for decentralised login into hyperledger fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-indy

I have a blockchain business network setup on hyperledger composer which interacts with Hyperledger Fabric. My business network is then exposed as a REST server which my angular application interacts with.

Im just wondering what is the best way to setup decetralised login functionality to my angular application?

Comment: others may answer, but these resources may help -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#node-app and part 2 of answer here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893410/hyperledger-composer-web-application-user-authentication

Comment: Thanks Paul. Do you know of nay self sovereign identity options? I know of Uport & Hyperledger Indy (Still in incubation) but I dont know of the pros/cons of each, do you have any resources on this?